# How to fetch the value stored at the value of any variable in perl

Tags: perl

Need to fetch the value stored at the value of any variable in perl. 
For example -

```
$a = 'b';
$b = '10;
```

Now how to fetch value $b using $a;

Comment: The `$a` is a (scalar) _variable_, which has string `b` as its value (coded with quotes `'b'`).  This `$b` that you ask about would be some other, completely unrelated, _variable_.

Comment: @zdim Ok.. is there any way to do it..

Comment: But, to do what?  You say "_fetch value `$b`_" -- what do you mean by that?  There is no value `$b` -- that would be some other variable. Your code `$a = 'b'` has no "_value `$b`_" in it.

Comment: Ah -- you mean to associate `'b'` and `$b` in some way?  They are completely unrelated, completely different things. The `$` in Perl is used to denote a variable, something that can have a value.  So `$b` is a name of a variable.  The other one, `'b'` is just a string, a value. Like `'hey there'` or `25.34`.  No relation whatsoever.

Comment: yes.. I want to use only a but want to fetch value @b

Comment: something like $$a ==> $b ==> 10

Comment: If you are thinking about building a _variable name_ from some given string (stored in another variable), that's called _symbolic references_ and the long honored advice is to _not do that_.  It is very tricky and leads to bugs.  Search for the term  and you'll find documentation (it  will also tell you to stay away from such techniques).

Comment: Here is my favourite link to explain: [Why it's a bad idea to use a variable as a variable name in perl](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)

Comment: why it is downvoted..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a great summary of why it's a bad idea to use a variable as a variable name](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html).

So I'm not going to tell you how to do it, because it's like teaching a toddler how to load a gun.

What you need here is a `hash`. Hashes are perl data structures which are key-value pairs.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %stuff;
$stuff{'b'} = 10;

my $target = 'b';
print $stuff{$target};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called a [symbolic reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Symbolic-references). Back before version 5, this was the only way in Perl to use a reference. Nowadays, it is considered deprecated and should be avoided. Use a hash instead. I'm only providing an example so you can spot it in any code you have to maintain and eliminate it.

Symbolic references only work for dynamic variables, that is, variables declare with `our` or [use vars](http://perldoc.perl.org/vars.html). Also note that you have to turn off `use strict refs` for it to work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $x = 'y';
our $y = 10;

{
    no strict qw( refs );
    print ${$x}, "\n";
}
```

BTW, you should also avoid using `$a` and `$b`. They are used by Perl's `sort` and can lead to confusion.

Answer (score -3):

I would not use this approach personally in my own code, but given what you asked you could use `eval` to evaluate the string value from one variable as perl variable name for another.

```
perl -e '$a='b'; $b=20; print eval("\$$a"), "\n";'
20
```

However this is not a great way to do things. Maybe your questions would get a better answer if you explained the purpose of why you want to be able to get the value from one variable based on the string name in another variable.

Comment: `s/not a great way/a really awful way/`

Comment: `eval` is misleading: there is no need for it. `perl -e '$a = 'b'; $b = 20; print $$a, "\n"'` works just fine

Comment: @Borodin - oh i didnt realise that

Comment: @Sobrique I agree i would never use this myself, i would normally use a hash or the likes.